# how to set mathfont using lualatex-math - lualatex

Tags: luatex

I have using `LuaLaTeX Version 1.12.0` and i want all the `display-math` font should be in `STIX` fonts. How to achieve this.

I have need to achieve this when using `lualatex-math` font.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,hyperref,fontspec,luacolor,lualatex-math}
    \setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
    \begin{document}
    \title{Article Title Here}
    \author{Author Here}
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    The investigations of cylindrically symmetric spacetimes can be traced back as far as to 1919 when Levi-Civita (LC) discovered a class of solutions of Einstein’s vacuum field equations, corresponding to static cylindrical spacetimes [\href{cqgab7bbabib1}{\textcolor{blue}{1}}].
    \begin{align*}{\frac{G\mathrm{μ}}{{{c}^{{2}}}}}=\mathcal{O}{\left({{\frac{{{E}^{{2}}}}{{{M}_{pl}^{{2}}}}}}\right)},\tag{1.1}\end{align*}
    where ${{{M}_{pl}}{\left({≡{\mathrm{ℏ}c/G}}\right)}}$ denotes the Planck mass.
    \begin{thebibliography}{000}
    \bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}{Aasi Jet alLIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations (2014) Constraints on cosmic strings from the LIGO-Virgo gravitational-wave detectors\textit{Phys. Rev. Lett.} \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{112}} } 

\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib2}{Abbott B Pet alLIGO and Virgo Collaborations (2016) Astrophysical implications of the binary black hole merger GW150914\textit{Astrophys. J. Lett.} \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{818}} }
    \end{thebibliography}
        \end{document}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: lualatex-math is not for fonts (and in a current tex system you don't need it at all), you need the unicode-math package if you want to use an unicode math font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@UlrikeFischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) has pointed out in a comment, `lualatex-math` is not suitable for loading fonts. In fact, if your TeX distribution is reasonably up to date, there's no reason for loading `lualatex-math` at all.

You mention that you want to use Stix fonts for math. Stix is a clone of Times Roman, but it hasn't been updated for quite a while. Instead of Stix, I suggest you use `XITS/XITS Math`, `Stix Two Text/Stix Two Math`, or the `newtxtext/newtxmath` pair.

One of the following three sets of instructions should work for you:

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

or

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

or

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
```

---

*Aside*: I can't help but make some comments about your code: You seem to be unusually eager to use curly braces in math mode. That said, I cannot see a good reason for writing

```
${{{M}_{pl}}{\left({≡{\mathrm{ℏ}c/G}}\right)}}$
```

when

```
$M_{pl}$ ($≡ℏc/G$)
```

produces the same output and does so without any code clutter.

Similarly, do consider replacing

```
{\frac{G\mathrm{μ}}{{{c}^{{2}}}}}=\mathcal{O}{\left({{\frac{{{E}^{{2}}}}{{{M}_{pl}^{{2}}}}}}\right)}
```

with

```
\frac{G\symup{μ}}{c^2} = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{E^2}{M_{pl}^2}\right)
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up posting: Since your document loads the `hyperref` package, I would replace

```
[\href{cqgab7bbabib1}{\textcolor{blue}{1}}]
```

with

```
\cite{cqgab7bbabib1}
```

In addition, I'd replace

```
\begin{thebibliography}{000}
\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}{Aasi Jet alLIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations (2014) Constraints on cosmic strings from the LIGO-Virgo gravitational-wave detectors\textit{Phys. Rev. Lett.} \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{112}} } 

\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib2}{Abbott B Pet alLIGO and Virgo Collaborations (2016) Astrophysical implications of the binary black hole merger GW150914\textit{Astrophys. J. Lett.} \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{818}} }
\end{thebibliography}
```

with

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}%{
Aasi J et al, LIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations (2014) Constraints on cosmic strings from the LIGO-Virgo gravitational-wave detectors. \textit{Phys. Rev. Lett.} 
%\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{112}}} 

\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib2}%{
Abbott B P et al, LIGO and Virgo Collaborations (2016) Astrophysical implications of the binary black hole merger GW150914. \textit{Astrophys. J. Lett.}  
%\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{818}}}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Observe, in particular, that I replaced `Aasi Jet alLIGO` with `Aasi J et al, LIGO` and `Abbott B Pet alLIGO` with `Abbott B P et al, LIGO`. These changes should make it a lot easier to actually comprehend what's written.

---

Summing up, here is how I would rewrite your example to make it more efficient.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,luacolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}

\begin{document}
\title{Article Title Here}
\author{Author Here}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The investigations of cylindrically symmetric spacetimes can be 
traced back as far as to 1919 when Levi-Civita (LC) discovered 
a class of solutions of Einstein's vacuum field equations, 
corresponding to static cylindrical spacetimes 
\cite{cqgab7bbabib1}.
\begin{equation*}
\frac{G\symup{μ}}{c^2} = 
\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{E^2}{M_{pl}^2}\biggr)\,,\tag{1.1}
\end{equation*}
where $M_{pl}$ ($≡ℏc/G$) denotes the Planck mass.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}%{
Aasi J et al, LIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations (2014) 
Constraints on cosmic strings from the LIGO-Virgo 
gravitational-wave detectors. \textit{Phys. Rev. Lett.} 
%\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{112}}} 

\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib2}%{
Abbott B P et al, LIGO and Virgo Collaborations (2016) 
Astrophysical implications of the binary black hole merger 
GW150914. \textit{Astrophys. J. Lett.}  
%\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{818}}}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The PDFTeX example should load `\usepackage{stix}` or `\usepackage{stix2}` to get the STIX fonts 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @Mico: I want to use `[\href{cqgab7bbabib1}{\textcolor{blue}{1}}]`. Because i don't want to use `\cite` command in `LaTeX`. How to hyperlink with Bib Cross-Ref to Bib ID? Please advise.

Comment: @Balaji - How do you create the bibliography at present? Entirely by Hand? Or with the help of a software tool?

Comment: @Balaji - Please also elaborate on what's keeping you from using `\cite`. It looks like you wish to use numeric-style citation call-outs. If the `hyperref` package is loaded, citation call-outs will automatically be made into hypertargets to the corresponding entries in the bibliography.

Comment: @Mico: I have converting `XML to LaTeX` using `Lua` Script. I have not needed auto generation bibliography and want to maintain `XML texts` in `LaTeX`. So that Lua script is using. I have needed when clicking `bibliography citation` is need to go for `bibliography ID`. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Balaji - I'm afraid I don't understand what "I have needed when clicking bibliography citation is need to go for bibliography ID" is supposed to entail. Please elaborate. You also said that you are converting an XML document to LaTeX -- is there some hyperlinking information associated with the individual formatted bibliographic entries? Is that what `cqgab7bbabib1` in `\href{cqgab7bbabib1}{\textcolor{blue}{1}}` refers to?

Comment: @Mico: XML Code is `[<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="cqgab7bbabib1">1</xref>]` its converted to LaTeX is `[\href{cqgab7bbabib1}{\textcolor{blue}{1}}]`. When i have click `[1]` its need to go respective `bibliography` place `\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}{Aasi Jet alLIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations` like `LaTeX`. I have updated my question also.

Comment: @Balaji - Please see the addendum I posted a few minutes ago,

Comment: @Mico: I don't want to use `\cite` tag when converting `XML to LaTeX`. Because when using `\cite` tag in LaTeX text will auto-generate. I need to avoid this. So that i have used `\href` tag. But when clicking `[\\href{cqgab7bbabib1}{\textcolor{blue}{1}}]` it's not going relevant `bibliography` part. I want the `\cite` options in different `LaTeX` coding.

Comment: My abject apologies, but I have no idea what "when using \cite tag in LaTeX text will auto-generate" might mean. Anyway, this site works best if each posting contains *just one question*; yours contains more than two. Since you disagree with the views I expressed in my answer, you may want to think about posting a *new query*, to focus on just the ctation call-out issue, explain your setup in greater detail, and explain why you wish to create citation call-outs *without* using `\cite` directives. (Maybe you will also explain why "Aasi Jet alLIGO..." is preferable to "Aasi J et al, LIGO...".)

Comment: @Mico: I have posted new questions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567768/without-cite-command-reference-with-reference-id-hyperlink