# Without \cite command reference with reference ID hyperlink

Tags: automation, lualatex-dev

I have using `LuaLaTeX Ver: 1.12.0`. I have converting `XML to LaTeX` using `Lua Script`. I have maintained the cross-links as per XML. I want to hyperref `cross-link` need to go corresponding hyperref `cross-id`. When clicking `\cite` it's going corresponding place. But when using `\hyperref` it's not going corresponding ID.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fontspec,luacolor,blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=blue}

\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}
\title{Article Title Here}
\author{Author Here}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The investigations of cylindrically symmetric spacetimes can be traced back as far as to 1919 when Levi-Civita (LC) discovered \textbf{HREF Command} [\href{cqgab7bbabib1}{1}] a class of \textbf{CITE Command} [\cite{cqgab7bbabib1}{1}]solutions of Einstein’s vacuum field equations, corresponding to static cylindrical spacetimes.

\blindtext[5]

\begin{thebibliography}{000}
\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}{Aasi J et al., LIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations (2014) Constraints on cosmic strings from the LIGO-Virgo gravitational-wave detectors \textit{Phys. Rev. Lett.} \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{112}}.} 

\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib2}{Abbott B P et al., LIGO and Virgo Collaborations (2016) Astrophysical implications of the binary black hole merger GW150914 \textit{Astrophys. J. Lett.} \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{818}}.}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: you can use `\hyperlink{cite.cqgab7bbabib1}{1}`, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553769/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It's now working fine and how to do web link. Example: `https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6382/ab7bba`. When i have using `\hyperref{web.https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6382/ab7bba}{https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6382/ab7bba}` it's not working.

Comment: use \url or \href for web links.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: How to Equations, table, section, figures etc manual hyperlink (ex: Equation: \hyperlink{cqgab7bbaeqn1_1}, Figure: \hyperlink{ref.cqgab7bbafig1}, Table: \hyperlink{ref.cqgab7bbatbl4}, section: \hyperlink{ref.cqgab7bbasec3} etc...) Any manuals/tutorials or web-links for this type of links?